# Assign multiple columns of numpy to one pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to populate a pandas dataframe in the following format

```
ID.  vector1              vector2        scalar
11  [0.34, 0.56, 0.99]   [0.24, 0.44]   9
23  [0.12, 0.66, 0.21]   [0.21, 0.24]   4
...
```

My input data is a numpy array of the following format

```
[
[11 0.34 0.56 0.99 0.24 0.44 9]
[23 0.12 0.66 0.21 0.21 0.24 4]
]
```

I tried playing with hsplit but couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert numpy slices to lists to add them to the dataframe.
Set up the dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

input_data = np.array([
    [11, 0.34, 0.56, 0.99, 0.24, 0.44, 9],
    [23, 0.12, 0.66, 0.21, 0.21, 0.24, 4]
])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID.': input_data[:,0].astype(np.int),
    'scalar':input_data[:,-1].astype(np.int)
})
```

Add `input_data` as lists to the dataframe

```
df['vector1'] = input_data[:,1:4].tolist()
df['vector2'] = input_data[:,4:6].tolist()
df[['ID.', 'vector1', 'vector2', 'scalar']]
```

Output

```
   ID.             vector1       vector2  scalar
0   11  [0.34, 0.56, 0.99]  [0.24, 0.44]       9
1   23  [0.12, 0.66, 0.21]  [0.21, 0.24]       4
```

---

### Micro-Benchmark

As both solutions are not vectorized, I was wondering which performance was impacted more.
Results

[image: benchmark results]

Code for the benchmark

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def create_data(n):
    input_data = np.array([
        [11, 0.34, 0.56, 0.99, 0.24, 0.44, 9],
        [23, 0.12, 0.66, 0.21, 0.21, 0.24, 4]
    ])
    return np.repeat(input_data, n, 0)

def add_with_list(input_data):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID.': input_data[:,0].astype(np.int),
        'scalar':input_data[:,-1].astype(np.int)
    })
    df['vector1'] = input_data[:,1:4].tolist()
    df['vector2'] = input_data[:,4:6].tolist()
    return df[['ID.', 'vector1', 'vector2', 'scalar']]

def add_with_apply(input_data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
    df2 = df[0].to_frame()
    df2.columns = ['ID.']
    df2['vector1'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[1], x[2], x[3]], axis=1)
    df2['vector2'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[4], x[5]], axis=1)
    df2['scalar'] = df[6]
    return df2

import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=create_data,
    kernels=[add_with_list, add_with_apply],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2,20)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

input = np.array([
    [11, 0.34, 0.56, 0.99, 0.24, 0.44, 9],
    [23, 0.12, 0.66, 0.21, 0.21, 0.24, 4]
])

df = pd.DataFrame(input)
```

If `df` is your starting data frame...

```
       0       1       2       3       4       5      6
    11.0    0.34    0.56    0.99    0.24    0.44    9.0
    23.0    0.12    0.66    0.21    0.21    0.24    4.0
```

You can combine columns as follows to get the output you're looking for.

The main thing that will help you is the lambda function - just put the columns you want in square brackets and make sure you set `axis=1` to pass the function to the dataframe's columns.

```
df2 = df[0].to_frame()
df2.columns = ['ID.']
df2['vector1'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[1], x[2], x[3]], axis=1)
df2['vector2'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[4], x[5]], axis=1)
df2['scalar'] = df[6]
```

Output

```
    ID.     vector1             vector2         scalar
    11.0    [0.34, 0.56, 0.99]  [0.24, 0.44]    9.0
    23.0    [0.12, 0.66, 0.21]  [0.21, 0.24]    4.0
```